# Sync Telegram contacts with the phone

Tags: contacts, huawei, telegram

I have lost my phone (**Huawei Mate 9**) recently. Unfortunately, I didn't have any backup from my contact. Now I use a **Huawei P8 Lite**. I see my contact in Telegram app and sync with my phone, but I can't use the telegram's contacts because they are read-only and I can only see them.

I looked up for a solution on the web, but I couldn't find any solution. Is there any way of using Telegram's contact or backup the?